.NET Core Multiple Cookie Authentication Schemes
I have created an ASP.NET Core 8 Razor pages project.
I setup two separate cookie authentication schemes:
s.AddAuthentication("MyScheme").AddCookie("MyScheme", o =>
{
    o.Cookie.Name = "MyScheme";
});
s.AddAuthentication("MyScheme1").AddCookie("MyScheme1", o =>
{
    o.Cookie.Name = "MyScheme1";
});

Then I sign in user for both (Razor page):
var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "123"),
        };

var userIdentityA = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyScheme");
var userPricipalA = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentityA);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyScheme", userPricipalA);

var userIdentityB = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyScheme1");
var userPricipalB = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentityB);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyScheme1", userPricipalB);

Two separate cookies were created.
Now I check for authentication:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    var identities = HttpContext.User.Identities.Select(i => i.AuthenticationType);
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var i in identities)
        {
            <li>@i</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>

And all I get is one (default) Identity. I would expect to have one user with two identities.
Do you know whether it is expected behavior? Authentication seems to always fall back to default.
You might ask - why to I need "simultaneous" sign/identity for same user? Well in my app I have two types of Identities:

(A) Full qualified user with account and broad access to features.
(B) User that is authorized with unique token link to particular action / actions. (User enters a unique URL and then should be signed in to be recognized on some pages for display dedicated messages and perform restricted actions).

For user can be authenticated as A, and might receive a link that will authorize his as B. Authorizing B should not overwrite earlier authentication as A.

"Well in my app I have two types of Identities:" - That is not a reason for doing this... you can accomodate different classes/tiers/types of users with a single Cookie Scheme instead by  controlling the Claims sets.

@Dai can you point me to examples to kind of solution you mention?

Actually, I think your approach might be more appropriate - if this article is anything to go by.

Working with claims might be the way... but that will require to handle mixed scenarios to invalidate already sign in users or authernticate not authenticated but with restriced role.

Does your controller ask for a particular scheme? The authentication middleware will try authenticating the request with default and forget about the rest if you don’t explicitly want both to be tested afaik

@PabloRecalde one case is that particular controller method should be available only for  B scenario, and other case is that on public (not restricted) page need to check whether user is in A or B scenario to display proper call to actions.

It is an expected behavior https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46528. From my comprehension you could try custom authentication middleware, to validate the user with own logic.
